# 5 level interdependent select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am so glad there are places like this so that people can have their problems answered, even for beginners like me! I have no clue were to go from here.

I am trying to create an interdependent that lists car makes, car models, year,  driver and scale.

I have created the fields and I can populate the car makes and car models, depending on the selection made. I am stuck on how to populate the 'year' field depending on the selections made in the previous boxes. I understand that the first box needs a function. Here is my code"

HTML:

```
<form name="selectionForm">
    <select name="makes" id="makes" size="3" style="width:125px">
        <option selected>Select a Make>></option>
    </select>
    <select name="models" id="models" size="3" style="width:125px"></select>
    <select name="years" id="years" size="3" style="width:125px"></select>
    <select name="drivers" id="drivers" size="3" style="width:125px"></select>
    <select name="scales" id="scales" size="3" style="width:125px"></select>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    initModels();

    function initModels() {
        var makesAndModels = {
            'Ford': ['Fiesta', 'Focus', 'Mondeo'],
            'Vauxhall': ['Astra', 'Cavalier', 'Vectra']
        };

        // Populate makes
        $.each(makesAndModels, function (k, v) {
            $('#makes').append('<option>' + k + '</option>');
        });

        // Populate models
        $('#makes').change(function() {
            var $models = $('#models');

            $models.html("");

            var models = makesAndModels[$(this).val()];

            $.each(models, function (k, v) {
                $models.append('<option>' + v + '</option>');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I would much appreciate some direction from yourselves because I have no clue where to go from here.

Comment: What does the data for year, drivers, and scale look like? Without the data, it's hard to write a solution.

Comment: I will try to show how I want is to display in the boxes
Vauxhall>>Astra>>2002>>James Thompson>>1:43
Vauxhall>>Vectra>>2000>>Jason Plato>>1:18
Ford>>Mondeo>>1998>>Nigel Mansell>>1:43

It would be great if you could create the select list with these options because there is alot more information to be put in.
If you could show me how to lay the code out, I will fill in the rest of the information.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so this is a long answer, and has taken me a long time to prepare, so bear with me (and get ready). Also, there is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FHZK/) below if you don't want to read this essay.

You'll be much better off storing each car as an individual object. If you have a database (or plan to have on in the future), this is how your data will be stored. Nested arrays also get exponentially painful, so it's best to stay clear of them. So to begin, we'll change your data structure to this:

```
var vehicles = [
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Fiesta', year: '2001', driver: 'me', scale: '1:43' },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Fiesta', year: '2005', driver: 'me', scale: '1:33' },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Focus', year: '1999', driver: 'you', scale: '1:18' },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Modeo', year: '1998', driver: 'Nigel Mansell', scale: '1:43' },
    { make: 'Vauxhall', model: 'Astra', year: '2002', driver: 'James Thompson', scale: '1:43' },
    { make: 'Vauxhall', model: 'Vectra', year: '2000', driver: 'Jason Plato', scale: '1:18' }
];
```

First thing's first, pre-propuate the initial makes select box:

```
var makes = get_distinct(vehicles, 'make');
$.each(makes, function(index, value) {
   $('select#make').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>')
});
```

Once you've that, you need to set up a way to filter the data. You'll need functions for filtering the vehicles by the selected options, and getting distinct values. The below `filter_vehicles()` is *horrible*, but I'm tired and it's late, so it'll have to do. You'd be better off making this dynamic, and there'll be an easy solution, but my brain is fried right now.

```
function filter_vehicles() {
    return $.grep(vehicles, function(n, i) {
        if ($('#driver').val() != '')
            return n.make == $('#make').val() && n.model == $('#model').val() && n.year == $('#year').val() && n.driver == $('#driver').val();
        if ($('#year').val() != '')
            return n.make == $('#make').val() && n.model == $('#model').val() && n.year == $('#year').val();
        if ($('#model').val() != '')
            return n.make == $('#make').val() && n.model == $('#model').val();
        else
            return n.make == $('#make').val();
    });
}

// returns distinct properties from an array of objects
function get_distinct(array, property) {
   var arr = [];

   $.each(array, function(index, value) {
       if ( $.inArray(value[property], arr) == -1 ) {
           arr.push(value[property]);
       }
   });

   return arr;
}
```

Then you'll need to update the select boxes. You can do it manually by targeting the change event on each individual select box, but you can also do it dynamically by attaching an event to all select boxes. I prefer this method, because it adds no overhead when adding additional fields.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    // don't execute if this is the last select element
    if ($(this).is(':last')) return;

    // clear all of the following select boxes, leaving a blank option
    $(this).nextAll().html('<option></option>');

    // get list of vehicles filtered by all the previous parameters
    var filtered_vehicles = filter_vehicles();

    // get the next select element
    var next = $(this).next();

    // get the distinct values from our list of filtered vehicles
    var values = get_distinct(filtered_vehicles, next.attr('id'));

    // append our options
    $.each(values, function(index, value) {
        next.append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>')
    });
});
```

All in all, you'll get something like this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FHZK/

This is all easier in SQL. So if you do have a database, you'd execute queries on the server to return the filtered set, which cuts out a bit of the yucky code above.

I have no idea why I wrote all this manually, because there's probably a jQuery plugin that already does it all (and better). But hey, it's done, I had fun, and all the code is commented to assist in your learning :)

Comment: This is absolutely amazing!!! Many, many, MANY thanks!!! I can tell you put alot into this. I feel really bad about asking another question, but... I am trying to put the javascript in to a page I have applied a template to... When I preview the page, the select lists do not work. Is there a <script> I am using incorrectly for the data to not populate the lists?

Comment: Have you got a link to the page where it's not working? It could be a few things. Check the console (using Firebug or Chrome developer tools) for any errors, and also chuck in some `console.log()` throughout the code to see if you can pinpoint the error.

Comment: I have replicated the problem I am having by selecting AngularJS 1.0.1 in the dropdown menu in the JSFiddle link at the top of your answer. The dropdown menus do not get populated with the options listed in the javascript. However, obviously it works in jQuery.

Can anyone help me to get this feature working?

Comment: That's because the code I wrote specifically used jQuery. You can use angularJS and jQuery side by side. Please don't unaccept answers when you change your code; instead post new questions. No one sees it.

Comment: I apologies for all the confusion but I am having trouble in getting your code to work still. Just to be completely sure, where/how do you put your code for the webpage to accept and understand it to make it work? Is it added to the page you want it to work on or is it put in a seperate file and linked to the other page?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put it, you can put it in the same file, or in an external one. Either way, jQuery needs to be included first. Check your browser console for errors. The code works in jsFiddle, so I can't debug on your machine without seeing it, unless you have a live example of it not working.

Comment: http://btccdiecastmodels.com/ModelIdeas/ This is the page i want it to work on. i have tried including the code in the head but no joy

Comment: Neither jQuery nor my code is included or referenced on that page. So first thing's first, include the code, then debug.

Comment: http://btccdiecastmodels.com/ModelIdeas/index.html sorry about that. I abviously forgot to save with your script in the file. done now. have run developer tool but brings up nothing

Comment: You haven't included jQuery. My script is written using jQuery, so as I mentioned in my previous comment, you need to include jQuery. You've also put my code into a `style` block, but it's a script. You need to put it inside a `script` block. I would recommend some basic web tutorials or getting help building the website. I don't mean to offend, but stackoverflow is for help, but not for spoon feeding you through every tiny step of building your site. Check out the [HTMLDog tutorials](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#years').change(function() {
  //do something like Populate models....
}
```

So, what's the difference?